# Angular 5 templating with router-outlet without sub urls

Tags: angular, angular-routing, templating

I would like to use a `Component` as a template in which I then have the `router-outlet` inject sub components.

I know I can easily do it with `children` routes, so I am doing it as follows.

My routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component: TemplateComponent, children: childRoutes }
];

export const childRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'page-one', component: PageOneComponent }
];
```

`TemplateComponent`:

```
<div class="some-awesome-template">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This works fine as long as I have an url following the pattern `/**/*`;

My problem is that I would like to use this templating logic for pages that do not have a sub url, e.g. `/about`.

Right now I'm doing it like so:

The `about` route:

```
{ path: 'about', component: TemplateComponent }
```

and then `TemplateComponent` looks like this:

```
<div class="some-awesome-template">
  <span [ngSwitch]="variableWithCurrentUrl">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'about'">
      <app-about></app-about>
    </span>
    <router-outlet *ngSwitchDefault></router-outlet>
  </span>
</div>
```

This works, but I would like to use `router-outlet` to inject `AboutComponent` as if it was a sub url, instead of manually doing it.

It is important, though, that not every `/**` route, gets the template, so that, for example, `/contact`, has its own template.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `main` route where `TemplateComponent` will be allocated and it will be child of root route:

```
export const childRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', 
    component: AppComponent
    children: [{
       path: 'main',
       component:TemplateComponent,
       children: childRoutes
    }, 
    {
       path: 'contract', 
       component: ContractComponent
    }
    ]
  }
];
```

**app.component.template:**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

- Then `/contract` doesn't use component:TemplateComponent
- Any routes after the `/main` will be allocated of `TemplateComponent` template

Comment: @CornelC, sorry. I mean path